# Survey - modify summary.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey

I'm trying to do two things, not sure if they are possible...

1. Remove the numbering in **Summary.aspx** (Only one question is asked so there's no need for numbering). DevTools has 
   `<h3 class="ms-standardheader, ms-vb"><b>1. Do you use fax at work?</b></h3>`
2. Move the Percent next to Yes and No.  I only need the % not the total. For example, Yes (0%), No (100%). Or I'm trying to hide the text for **Number of Responses**. DevTools has `<td class="ms-SurveyHBarLabel" style="width:70pt"><label class="ms-hidden">Number Of Responses</label>0&nbsp;<label class="ms-hidden">Percentage Of Responses</label>(0%)&nbsp;</td>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JavaScript code for your reference, add the code into script editor web part in the summary.aspx page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3[class='ms-standardheader, ms-vb']>b").each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).text().split(".")[1]);
    });
    $("td[class='ms-vb'][style='padding-bottom: 5px;']").each(function(){
        if($(this).text()=="Yes"||$(this).text()=="No"){
            var percentage=$(this).closest("tr").next().find(".ms-SurveyHBarLabel").text().split("(")[1];
            $(this).text($(this).text()+" ("+percentage);
        }       
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.ms-SurveyHBarLabel{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: the 2nd part (displaying % next to yes/no) doesn't work in Chrome or Edge. Works well in IE though.  Thanks

Comment: I got it to work in Chrome by replacing the `[style='padding-bottom: 5px;']` with `[style='padding-bottom:5px']`